# illegal characters in facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i was trying to get how many facebook likes an url got, through facebook graph api.
to get the likes i need to get the content from this url:
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=URL

for example, try to get into this url:
"graph.facebook.com/?id=http://stackoverflow.com"
you will see how many "shares" the url got. shares is the sum of shares and likes, so every thing was working good when i was trying to this.

the problem start when i use special charcters. when i using the "?" charcter everything work okey. but when i use "&" charcter the url cuts itself.

try this:
"graph.facebook.com/?id=http://stackoverflow.com?p=blabla&a=fsdf"
you can see in this page that the id actullay cut itself when it get to the "&" charcter and the page ends like this:

```
{
   "id": "http://stackoverflow.com?p=blabla"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php):

```
$url = 'graph.facebook.com/?id='.urlencode('http://stackoverflow.com?p=blabla&a=fsdf');
```

FB return:

```
{
  id: "http://stackoverflow.com?p=blabla&a=fsdf"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `&amp;` instead of `&`.